# "go to the bathroom one time", is it idiomatic to say that?

Tags: idiomatic-language

To describe How I was busy, I could say

> I worked the whole day.

to emphasize the non stop work, I guess I could add more

> I worked the whole day, I didn't even go to the bathroom **one time**.

or

> I worked the whole day, I didn't even go to the bathroom, not even **one time**.

My concern is the part **one time**, is it idiomatic to say that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, adding "one time" is completely idiomatic and natural sounding. Particularly your first sentence. All though I would replace "the whole day" with "all day".

Having "even" twice in that second sentence is a little awkward. I would either say:

> I worked all day. I didn't even go to the bathroom one time.

Or

> I was so busy all day, I didn't go to the bathroom. Not even once.

Comment: 'One time' is more American, 'once' is more rest-of-world.

Comment: Native AmE speaker. I probably use "once" at least as often as "one time", maybe more

Comment: Native BrE speaker, I use 'x times' if x is three or more.